# From the laravel documentation, what do the 'sidebar' and 'content' ask for: a separate child document or something that is still to be made?

Tags: laravel

So i'm verry new to stackoverflow and Laravel so here goes nothing!

I do not get the laravel documentation where the yield and section call for certain things because i don't know what those called things are.
So if u see this documentation:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>App Name - @yield('title')</title>
</head>
<body>
    @section('sidebar')
        This is the master sidebar.
    @show

    <div class="container">
        @yield('content')
    </div>
</body>
```

The title, sidebar and content are confusing my tiny brain and its stressing me.
Pleas explain me.
(Also i'm not a native english speaker sorry for any typos.)

Answer (score 1):

**Example**

Consider you have a simple `index` page that consists of basic html and css, now you will 2 more pages `about` and `contacts` like this page, first thing you will notice that all 3 pages have the same layouts and section but they are different in page `title` and `content`

so instead of rewriting those section over and over again in every new page we have to do something else

**Solution**

We can make a general skeleton of those pages and it's called `master` layout like so

```
<html>
   <head>
     <title>App Name - @yield('title')</title>
   </head>
   <body>
   <div class="container">
      @yield('content')
   </div>
  </body>
```

now every new page you create will `extends` that layout and each page have to add it's `title` and `content`

```
@extends('master')
@section('title')
   About Us
@endsection
@section('content')
   <div>about us page content goes here</div>
@endsection
```

> about us page now has it's own unique data but it has the layout
> with other pages.

Note that: a `yield` in a layout page represents a `section` in extended page

Comment: Thank yo so much for taking your time and explaining me this! It makes it so much easier to understand. I could cry right now 'cus i'm so happy.